# Elasticsearch / Python / Proxy

Tags: python, elasticsearch, proxy

im new to stackoverflow, so if i make a mistake im sorry.

I have to write a python script which collects some data with Elasticsearch and then write the data to a database. I am struggling collecting the data with elasticsearch, because the company i work is behind a proxy.

The script works without a proxy.. but i dont know how to pass down the proxy settings to Elasticsearch.

following code works without a proxy:

```
es = Elasticsearch(['https://user:password@logs.net/elasticsearch'])
res = es.search(index=index, body=request, search_type="count")
```

i tried the following when i am behind the proxy:

```
es = Elasticsearch(['https://user:password@logs.net/elasticsearch'], _proxy = 'http://proxy.org', _proxy_headers = {'basic_auth': 'user:pw'})
res = es.search(index=index, body=request, search_type="count")
return res
```

Does anyone know the keywords which i have to pass down Elasticsearch so it uses the proxy?

any help would be nice.

thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got an answer on GitHub:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/275#issuecomment-143781969

Thanks a ton again!

```
from elasticsearch import RequestsHttpConnection

class MyConnection(RequestsHttpConnection):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        proxies = kwargs.pop('proxies', {})
        super(MyConnection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.session.proxies = proxies

es = Elasticsearch([es_url], connection_class=MyConnection, proxies = {'https': 'http://user:pw@proxy.org:port'})


print(es.info())
```

Comment: This is an outdated answer. `RequestsHttpConnection` does not exist anymore in new versions of `elasticsearch`!!

Answer (score 4):

Generally, we don't need to add extra code for proxy, the python low-level module shall be able to use system proxy (i.e. `http_proxy`) directly.

In the later release (at least 6.x) we can use `requests` module instead of `urllib3` to solve this problem nicely, see https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/transports.html

```
# make sure the http_proxy is in system env
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
es = Elasticsearch([es_url], connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection)
```

Another possible problem is `search` using `GET` method as default, it is rejected by my old cache server (squid/3.19), extra parameter `send_get_body_as` shall be added, see https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/#environment-considerations

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch(send_get_body_as='POST')
```

Answer (score 1):

For people that needs to use elasticsearch 8.X.X and that do not want to export `http_proxy` and `no_proxy` environment variables. They can do this:

```
from elastic_transport import RequestsHttpNode
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch


class CustomHttpNode(RequestsHttpNode):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.session.proxies = {"https": "http://localhost:8888"}


es = Elasticsearch(
    "https://localhost:9200",        
    basic_auth=("user", "password"),
    node_class=CustomHttpNode,
)
print(es.info())
```

https://github.com/elastic/elastic-transport-python/issues/53#issuecomment-1447903214